# Drawing a 16x16 grid of random pixels in Core Graphics

Tags: cocoa-touch, random, drawing, core-graphics, pixel

How would I draw a UIImage in Core Graphics with dimensions 16x16 filled with random pixels at random coordinates and random grayscale color? This seems slightly impossible to do at the moment...

EDIT: Perhaps I should start with a diagonal line texture? My problem is filling in each pixel one by one. Doesn't seem doable in Core Graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a buffer as many bytes long as you want pixels (so, in this case, `16 * 16`).

Fill this buffer by reading from /dev/random.

Pass this buffer to [the `CGImageCreate` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreate) using `kCGImageAlphaNone`.

Once you have created a CGImage, it is trivial to [create a UIImage from it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage%3a). Depending on your requirements, you can actually create up to eight “random” UIImages from the same CGImage by [specifying different orientation values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage%3ascale%3aorientation%3a).

ETA: You might also try creating a two-byte-per-pixel buffer and image. Then, by using each of [the endianness flags](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little), you can create two “random” CGImages from the same buffer, for a total of 16 “random” UIImages. However, I don't know whether two-byte-per-pixel no-alpha grayscale is supported on any version of iOS; [the Quartz 2D Programming Guide lists only Mac OS X version numbers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB).

Comment: Beautiful answer! Worked perfectly :D